I get many-to-many error from the promql dividing a vector with the same vector
I just started to study promql and playing with it.
And studying two vector operators, I tried to the promql below expecting to get 1 for all samples.
Query
(sum by (__name__) ({__name__=~"count_.*_failure", entityId="Service"}))
/
(sum by (__name__) ({__name__=~"count_.*_failure", entityId="Service"}))

But got many-to-many error.
I can't understand why it fails.
I divided a vector with the same vector so I thought one-to-one vector match can happen
and show a graph with all values are 1s.

Division, like most other operations drops metrics name. Without that name labelsets in your expression are not unique, hence the error.

@markalex Thanks for your comment really. I could understand why it makes error by your help. By the way, where did you get that like most other operations drops metrics name?
Ah sorry, I found that from the official document.
The metric name is dropped.
